# How to use gatsby-image and contentful

Tags: gatsby, gatsby-image

I'm trying to handle the retina images in a Gatsby project. My content provider is Contentful. I'm uploading the 2x images. I'm currently using the Gatsby-images plugin. To get the correct image I'm using:

```
    images{
      fluid{
        ...GatsbyContentfulFluid_withWebp
      }
    }
```

I also using the tag that supposes to handle retina images.

```
<Img fluid={image.fluid} alt="" class="mw-100 d-inline-block" />
```

But.. at the end of the day. I'm getting the wrong images.

I'm getting the 800w so It seems that I'm getting one breakpoint behind the image.

https://images.ctfassets.net/rz477be2kwhw/1NwXY8PIrEYSXJKPH6iu6L/5d5a6ac1f2b45e5a4de2478b94e4d3c5/Grupo_1510_3x.png?w=800&h=701&q=50&fm=webp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**I've solved the issue.** There were two issues, by default Gatsby Plugin Sharp (https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-sharp/) uses quality 50 and maxWidth 800px. I just update qualify 100 and maxWidth of 2500 since I was waiting for bigger images.

```
fluid(maxWidth: 2500, quality: 100){
 ...GatsbyContentfulFluid_withWebp
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, by default gatsby image sets quality to 50 and width to 800 for fluid images. However, you can always change the quality, maxwidth, and srcsetbreakpoints.

```
fluid(maxWidth: 1400 , quality: 100) {
  ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
}
```